# Why is my worksheet change event not working?

Tags: vba, events

I am trying to make a sub that changes the months according to a dropdown list. So everytime I change the month in the dropdown C3, it should copy the right month from a different aleady prepared sheet. As a sub it works just fine, but as an event it doesn't. I am guessing it is a problem with the event and the select case. Any ideas?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim month As String

If Target.Address = Range("C3") Then

    Range("A5:H27").Clear
    month = Range("C3")

    Select Case month
    
        Case "Januar"
    
            Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Input").Range("A3:A25").Copy Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Time Sheet").Range("A5")
    
        Case "Februar"
    
            Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Input").Range("B3:B25").Copy Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Time Sheet").Range("A5")
    
        Case "März"
    
            Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Input").Range("C3:C25").Copy Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Time Sheet").Range("A5")
        
        Case "April"
    
            Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Input").Range("D3:D25").Copy Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Time Sheet").Range("A5")
        
        Case "Mai"
    
            Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Input").Range("E3:E25").Copy Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Time Sheet").Range("A5")
        
        Case "Juni"
    
            Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Input").Range("F3:F25").Copy Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Time Sheet").Range("A5")
        
        Case "Juli"
    
            Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Input").Range("G3:G25").Copy Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Time Sheet").Range("A5")
        
        Case "August"
    
            Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Input").Range("H3:H25").Copy Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Time Sheet").Range("A5")
        
        Case "September"
    
            Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Input").Range("I3:I25").Copy Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Time Sheet").Range("A5")
        
        Case "Oktober"
    
            Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Input").Range("J3:J25").Copy Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Time Sheet").Range("A5")
        
        Case "November"
    
            Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Input").Range("K3:K25").Copy Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Time Sheet").Range("A5")
        
        Case "Dezember"
    
            Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Input").Range("L3:L25").Copy Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Time Sheet").Range("A5")
    
    End Select

End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try if the event itself works? I mean, put a break on the code first line (after declarations) and make a change. Does the code stops on the break? If not, you may not have events enabled. Try a simple sub with only a code line `Application.EnableEvents = True`, run it and try again. When stopped, run the code line by line pressing F8 and see where the problem is,..

Comment: Then, when it will start working, the event will be triggered twice, when use `Range("A5:H27").Clear`. This line have to be placed between `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = True`. Is the event code placed correctly in the sheet code module where the drop down exists?  Anyhow, the code should be more compact if you declare two sheets, set them a the beginning and using as `wsT..Range("L3:L25").Copy wsTS..Range("A5")`. And declare a new variable: `Dim copyRange As Range`, then using `Set copyRange = wsT..Range("L3:L25")`, or `Set copyRange = wsT..Range("D3:D25")`

Comment: Only the last line will be `copyRange.Copy wsTS..Range("A5")`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, copy the next code in the sheet code module where the drop down in discussion exists:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim month As String, copyRange As Range, wsI As Worksheet, wsTS As Worksheet

 If Target.Address = Range("C3").Address Then
    Set wsI = Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Input")
    Set wsTS = Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Time Sheet")
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
     Range("A5:H27").Clear
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    month = CStr(Target.Value)
    
    Select Case month
        Case "Januar"
            Set copyRange = wsI.Range("A3:A25")
        Case "Februar"
            Set copyRange = wsI.Range("B3:B25")
        Case "März"
            Set copyRange = wsI.Range("C3:C25")
        Case "April"
            Set copyRange = wsI.Range("D3:D25")
        Case "Mai"
            Set copyRange = wsI.Range("E3:E25")
        Case "Juni"
            Set copyRange = wsI.Range("F3:F25")
        Case "Juli"
            Set copyRange = wsI.Range("G3:G25")
        Case "August"
            Set copyRange = wsI.Range("H3:H25")
        Case "September"
            Set copyRange = wsI.Range("I3:I25")
        Case "Oktober"
            Set copyRange = wsI.Range("J3:J25")
        Case "November"
            Set copyRange = wsI.Range("K3:K25")
        Case "Dezember"
            Set copyRange = wsI.Range("L3:L25")
    End Select
    If Not copyRange Is Nothing Then
        copyRange.Copy wsTS.Range("A5")
    Else
        MsgBox Target.Value & " could not be used in Select Case..."
    End If
 End If
End Sub
```

Now change the values in "C3". If the event is not triggered, run the next code and try again:

```
Sub EventsEnabled
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If I could see the range in "different already prepared sheet", based on what the list validation is done and the months enumeration comes in logic order, the `Select Case` can be avoided and calculate the necessary range, according to the months string position in the list, in a single code line...

**Edited**:

Please, test the more compact code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim month As String, copyRange As Range, wsI As Worksheet, wsTS As Worksheet
 Dim wsSpec As Worksheet, rngMonths As Range, mtch
 
 If Target.Address = Range("C3").Address Then
    Set wsI = Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Input")
    Set wsTS = Workbooks("Timesheet").Worksheets("Time Sheet")
    Set wsTS = Worksheets("the special sheet...")  'your special worksheet...
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
     Range("A5:H27").Clear
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    month = CStr(Target.Value)
    Set rngMonths = wsSpec.Range("A2:L2")
    mtch = Application.match(month, rngMonths, 0)
    If Not isserror(mtch) Then
        Set rngCopy = wsTS.Range(wsTS.cells(3, mtch), wsTS.cells(25, mtch))
        copyRange.Copy wsTS.Range("A5")
    Else
        MsgBox Target.Value & " could not be found in the months range..."
    End If
   Set rngCopy = sh.Range(sh.cells(3, mtch), sh.cells(25, mtch))
 End If
End Sub
```

Not tested, of course, but this should be the logic. If something wrong, please tell me what error and on which line.

Now, I am leaving my office...

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked just fine, my biggest issue is, that I don't realy understand why it did work and my version why didn't. Normally I don't have to enable any events via code, it is strange that I had to in this case. Not to mention I don't get why it has to be false first and only then true...
Why was the version with cop and paste worong, why does it have to check if it is an empty range or not?
Why the else clause with the message box? There shouldn't be any case where the range is empty, I have no "Please select" in my dropdown.

Comment: The months names are in line 2 from A to L on the sheet with the workdays respectively until the 25 th line(since they are missing weekdays). Depends on the month until which line the days last.

Comment: @StingerWolf No need to run the code enabling events from now on, except the case when something wrong happens in your code and it stops **before enabling events**, like it probably happened in your case. Then, when you delete something on the sheet **the event will be triggered again**. So, you save Excel resources to cancel the next useless triggering. The code must check if is an empty range in case **it is a misspelled month name or on the sheet, or in the code**. Otherwise, if such a situation may occur, trying to copy an empty range will raise an error.